# Compare two Json files using Apache Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, compare, difference

I am new to Apache Spark and I am trying to compare two json files.
My requirement is to find out that which key/value is added, removed or modified and what is its path.

To explain my problem, I am sharing the code which I have tried with a small json sample here.

Sample Json 1 is:

> {
> "employee": {
> "name":       "sonoo",
> "salary":      57000,
> "married":    true
> }   }

Sample Json 2 is:

> {
> "employee": {
> "name":       "sonoo",
> "salary":      58000,
> "married":    true
> }   }

My code is:

```
//Compare two multiline json files
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
//Load first json file
val jsonData_1 = sqlContext.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("D:\\File_1.json").values)

//Load second json file
val jsonData_2 = sqlContext.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("D:\\File_2.json").values)
//Compare both json files
jsonData_2.except(jsonData_1).show(false)
```

The output which I get on executing this code is:

```
+--------------------+
|employee            |
+--------------------+
|{true, sonoo, 58000}|
+--------------------+
```

But here only one field i.e. *salary* was modified so output should be only the updated field with its path.

Below is the expected output details:

```
[
  {
    "op" : "replace",
    "path" : "/employee/salary",
    "value" : 58000
  }
]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming each json has an identifier, and that you have two json groups (e.g. folders), you need to compare b/w the jsons in the two groups:

1. Load the jsons from each group into a dataframe, providing a schema matching the structure of the son. After this, you have two dataframes.
2. Compare the jsons (by now rows in a dataframe) by joining on the identifiers, looking for mismatched values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I am new to Apache Spark, could you please provide any sample code in your answer?

Comment: Agree with prem that the hard part isn't knowing what to do, it's knowing how to do it.